# Troubles with Background Resposive

Tags: css, html, responsive

I'm have a problem with responsive background on Chrome mobile. My problem is only with Chrome.

What I gonna do?

```
    body{
     background-image: url(images/home.png);
     background-position:center;
     background-color:#2e4053;
     background-size:cover;
    }

  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1100px) {
    body {
     background-image: url(images/homemobile.png);
     background-position:center;
     background-color:#2e4053;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -ms-background-size:cover;
     -o-background-size:cover;
     }
    }
```

Chrome on desktop: http://prntscr.com/necegy 
Chrome Mobile: http://prntscr.com/necf2a 
Firefox Mobile: http://prntscr.com/necf8t

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Make sure you add background-repeat: no-repeat
2. Make sure your page is forced to a minimum height of 100%
3. Also you don't need to repeat the entire style in the media query – just the one changed

... something like this

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/home.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-color: #2e4053;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1100px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(images/homemobile.png);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to give margin and padding to the body too.

```
body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Please be careful using background attachment fixed – it's the one of the most buggy background properties (chrome, safari, iOS...)